# Ionic2 web app routing configuration

Tags: ionic2

I  am working on ionic2 project, which is web project (i.e. runs as a website on browsers not a mobile app). Here I am facing difficulty to give specific URL for pages. How do I implement routing in my project ?

I also worked with angular2. Where we can give URL to components. But here that thing is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this website: https://www.joshmorony.com/a-simple-guide-to-navigation-in-ionic-2/
and read up on the nav controller here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Some Context: While Ionic2 does use the native browser for each platform, it uses a special controller to change routes

> NavController is the base class for navigation controller components like Nav and Tab. You use navigation controllers to navigate to pages in your app. At a basic level, a navigation controller is an array of pages representing a particular history (of a Tab for example). This array can be manipulated to navigate throughout an app by pushing and popping pages or inserting and removing them at arbitrary locations in history.

Before diving deeper into Ionic I suggest obtaining an understanding of this controller.

This sample ionic project will also help with the understanding of navController:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-sidemenu

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I know about nav controller of ionic which uses push and pop actually my problem is that I want to show URL of pushed page.

Comment: Can you provide an example?